# android getUriForFile fails for external_files_path

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

*** NEW INFO ***
Singlestepping into the FileProvider code, I see that *external-files-path* is not actually rooted at */storage/emulated/0/* but at */storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.perinote.perinote/files/*. So, I ask the question, how do I share a file in external storage /DCIM?

---

I'm passing an "external" file to an Intent and getting an "IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains ..." error.

Not sure what's missing. Doing something similar with a "cache" file works.

Here's my provider part of my manifest:

```
    <provider
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
      android:authorities="com.perinote.image_access"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true"
      android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

The "filepaths.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-files-path
    path="DCIM/Perinote/" name="images" /> <!-- must be same as ImageData.getPerinoteDirectory -->
</paths>
```

And the snip of code, where "file" is the file name (without path) in question:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType ("plain/text");
intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {address});
intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile (getContext (), "com.perinote.image_access", file);
intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult (intent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_SEND_EMAIL);
```

It's failing in getUriForFile().

When I use a file manager app on the device, the file is definitely there, under DCIM/Perinote/

For example, using the debugger, *file* is "IMG_20171130_204015.jpg".
And opening an *explorer* window on Windows shows the path

> This PC\Moto G (4)\Internal shared storage\DCIM\Perinote

and the file appears in the list below.

Comment: You should start with changing `<external-files-path` to `<external-path`.

Comment: `FileProvider.getUriForFile (getContext (), "com.perinote.image_access", file);` You should of course have started showing us how you build up that `file` ,instance. Tell the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()` please.

Comment: `the file is definitely there, under DCIM/Perinote/`. That is a relative path. You should tell full path to begin with.

Comment: Thank you. You solved my problem. Please provide an answer and I'll give you credit. I has missed "external-path" as one of the options, and that was the crucial element. As for relative path, I had tried it both ways, with a relative and a full path, but of course, both failed because of the "paths" element. Sorry for not stating that in my post.

Comment: Is it related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72411188 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with changing `<external-files-path` to `<external-path.`.